# Não consigo compilar código c++ ou c em nenhuma ide

Tags: c, c++, mingw

A um tempo vejo que só consigo compilar código c ou c++ no meu cmd. E não consigo compilar em nenhuma ide. 
Sempre que tento compilar aparece o erro:

> ```
> c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/8.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe:
> ```
>
> cannot open output file projeto.exe: Permission denied
>       collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status.

O que eu posso fazer?

Comment: Eu já tive esse problema de "Permission denied", e por incrível que pareça foi resolvido apenas ativando um serviço do windows no services.msc Encontrei a solução aqui: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7655471/ld-exe-cannot-open-output-file-permission-denied Espero que dê certo para você também.

Comment: Você não está a compilar com o programa já a correr ? Se for o caso quando o corre ele fica bloqueando e não dá para compilar até terminar a execução, pois compilar implica substituir o .exe que está no momento bloqueado.